# View Controller-specific orientation on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad

I'm developing an iPad app on iOS 8.

My application supports different orientations, and each `UIViewController` has a specific orientation.

I found this code:

```
 [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:
 [NSNumber numberWithInteger: UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait]
                            forKey:@"orientation"];
```

It works, however when the user rotates iPad my application rotates accordingly.

I need to lock each view controller.

Comment: @Duangumporn link given by Aaron brager is best solution, but i doubt that it will not work when you are using tabbar controll in iPad let me know if is the case for you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop the Orientation for whole application follow this Question: http://tinyurl.com/nglky3z

Or If you want to stop the orientation on few View Controllers Follow this Answer: 
http://tinyurl.com/lrv2abw

If you want to stop the Orientation on few View Controllers, Follow the 2nd question. In the Second question person is using the UITabcontroller, so he made the Category for TabContoller, and put the code in that. If you are not using UITabController, you might need the Category of NavigationController